# position absolute make flexbox break, react

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, flexbox, css-position

when i make ".card-name" absolute position to class ".card", the flexbox ".cards-container" not showing and all the height get 0 even after i have explicitly mentioned.

```
function ExpandingCards() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="cards-container">
        <Card
          card_img="https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg"
          id="1"
        />
        <Card
          card_img="https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg"
          id="1"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

component card

```
function Card(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div
        id={props.id}
        className="card"
        style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.card_img})` }}
      >
        <h4 className="card-name">cardName</h4>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Css for each**

```
.card {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
.card-name {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.cards-container {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
}
```

Please help with details why this happens

result

[image]

Comment: What did you expect? `position:absolute` means that the height of that element is ignored when computing the height of the parent.

Comment: @Paulie_D that why i have explicitly mentioned the height on relative element. if i remove display:flex property from ".cards-container "  it showing the background image. why it so?

Comment: 100% of what? If the parent of the container's height is not stated or calculable it will default to auto/0.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D parents container is ".cards-container" having height 90vh. even if we modify the ".card" height and set it to 100px or something, even after also its height collapsing.